# libwebsockets: How to close connection

Tags: c, websocket

I’m using [libwebsockets](http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets) to run both a websocket server and a client (actually in the same executable). Is there a way to gracefully *close* a connection?

I know I can return a negative int in my callback function to make the connection abort, but that feels more like something that happens on an error. In some example code on some random blog, I found a reference to a function `libwebsocket_close_and_free_session` but that does not exist (any longer?) in the library code.

Ideally, I would like to be able to close a *different* connection from within the callback handler than the one being called (i.e. to interpret a command like “close the other connection”).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the previous version of the libwebsockets the public API had the `libwebsocket_close_and_free_session` function.

The previous test code used that to close the connections e.g.

```
if (mirror_lifetime == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "closing mirror session\n");
    libwebsocket_close_and_free_session(context,
        wsi_mirror, LWS_CLOSE_STATUS_GOINGAWAY);
```

but the new test code uses the return -1 approach so I assume that's the intended graceful approach

```
mirror_lifetime--;
if (!mirror_lifetime) {
    fprintf(stderr, "closing mirror session\n");
    return -1;
}
```

The function still exists in the library code but it's now in the `private-libwebsocket.h` file.
I'm not sure if you can access it (or should be accessing it) from there in your code. If you could it would be the perfect API for you as you can close other connections as long as you have their `struct libwebsocket *wsi` pointer.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if the close on the remote end was clean? If you just return a -1 from the callback it closes the other end but there's no way to differentiate between a network connection drop and an I-intended-to-cleanly-close, is there?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for a function [lws_set_timeout( wsi, reason, timeout )](https://libwebsockets.org/lws-api-doc-v3.0-stable/html/group__timeout.html) .

The timeout can be also LWS_TO_KILL_SYNC for immediate close the session.